# RBS Configuration on another content database Fail

Tags: sql, rbs, 2012

I faced a problem while configuring RBS on another content database after installing it on a content database.

The problem is that inside the log file I found the expression "Configuration completed successfully." However I did not find the related Database tables for this content database.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use Powershell to check if RBS is enabled for that site collection or not.

Comment: Thank you Amal but I checked that and I found that RBS is not installed even

Comment: In that case you might have missed some steps. I would suggest you try again.

Comment: I tried again also and the same result, even though I restarted the SQL server and nothing changed. Could you tell me what are the steps you used